# DateTime query searching

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a sample database.

```
 Name          CheckIn                 CheckOut
Jake      2017-08-02 00:00:00    2017-08-05 00:00:00
Rowan     2017-08-07 00:00:00    2017-08-11 00:00:00
Xander    2017-08-08 00:00:00    2017-08-10 00:00:00
Anna      2017-08-09 00:00:00    2017-08-15 00:00:00
Nat       2017-08-11 00:00:00    2017-08-14 00:00:00
```

For example user search the date of **2017-08-08** to **2017-08-10**. User want to search the all data that who has the date of **8, 9** and **10**. Ex. Rowan choose the date of checkin in 7 and checkout in 10, So rowan had the the date of 7, **8, 9 10** and 11. This is the output that i want.

```
Name          CheckIn                 CheckOut
Rowan     2017-08-07 00:00:00    2017-08-11 00:00:00
Anna      2017-08-09 00:00:00    2017-08-15 00:00:00
Xander    2017-08-08 00:00:00    2017-08-10 00:00:00
```

I really dont know the logic of reservation searching help me. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check for *overlapping* intervals, then this is the way:

```
SELECT Name, CheckIn, CheckOut
FROM mytable
WHERE CheckIn <= '2017-08-10' AND CheckOut >= '2017-08-08';
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/PWKD92245)

To better understand this you can draw a sketch depicting the search interval `[2017-08-08, 2017-08-10]` against the reservation interval `[CheckIn, CheckOut]`:

[image]

If:

- `CheckOut` < '2017-08-08' then the reservation interval comes *before* the search interval
- `CheckIn` > '2017-08-10` then the reservation interval comes *after* the search interval

Hence none of the above conditions must hold if we want the intervals to overlap. So we end up with the following predicates:

```
`CheckOut` >= '2017-08-08' AND `CheckIn` <= '2017-08-10`
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test.TableName WHERE 
(DATE(CheckIn) BETWEEN DATE('2017-08-08') AND DATE('2017-08-10') )
OR
(DATE(CheckOut) BETWEEN DATE('2017-08-08') AND DATE('2017-08-10') )
OR 
(DATE('2017-08-08') BETWEEN DATE(CheckIn) AND DATE(CheckOut))
OR
(DATE('2017-08-10') BETWEEN DATE(CheckIn) AND DATE(CheckOut));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `between` condition  for `start` and `end` date  in `where` clause for `check_in` and `check_out` columns as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE check_in BETWEEN '2017-08-07' AND '2017-08-10'
  OR check_out BETWEEN '2017-08-07' AND '2017-08-10'
```

**Result**

```
name    check_in              check_out
-------------------------------------------------
Rowan   07.08.2017 00:00:00   11.08.2017 00:00:00
Xander  08.08.2017 00:00:00   10.08.2017 00:00:00
Anna    09.08.2017 00:00:00   15.08.2017 00:00:00
```

You can check the demo [here](http://rextester.com/QIW56577)